# Change Chrome homepage by time of day

Tags: chrome, workflow

In the morning, I always start my day by opening up Chrome and checking my email, but somehow I always forget to clock in in our web based timeclock.

I don't use any desktop calendar solutions and I'd prefer not to, so a calendar reminder is out.

Rather, I'd like to have my homepage be the web based timeclock page, but only during the first couple hours of the day. Is there anything out there (like a Chrome plugin) that can help me accomplish this?

Comment: You could [code](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?168372-Redirect-Based-on-Time-of-Day) a basic redirection page and make it your homepage.

Comment: @VicAche: Good idea, feel free to make this an answer.

Comment: @VicAche This is what I ended up using, so post it as an answer and I'll gladly accept it! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are confident with coding/copy pasting, you could make a local home.html file that, using some javascript, redirects you to wherever you wanna be redirected.
Below is an example script that you could use after making necessary adjustments (I found this version here: [Redirect Based on Time of Day](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?168372-Redirect-Based-on-Time-of-Day))
It shouldn't be hard to make it an auto redirection if you prefer that.

> ```
> <HTML>
> <HEAD>
> <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
> <!--
> function ampmRedirect(dayURL, nightURL)
> {
> var currentTime;
> var currentHour;
>
> // get the current date and time
> currentTime = new Date();
>
> // returns the hour in military time
> currentHour = currentTime.getHours();
> // check if the hour is between 6pm and 6am
> if ((currentHour < 6) || (currentHour > 17)) {
> window.location = nightURL;
> } else {
> window.location = dayURL;
> }
> }
> // -->
> </SCRIPT>
> </HEAD>
> <BODY>
> <FORM>
> Click here to go to the next page:<BR>
> <INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Next"
> onClick="ampmRedirect('day.htm','night.htm')">
> </FORM>
> </BODY>
> </HTML>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Linux (Ubuntu) with Google Chrome (not Chromium) you can try this (not always working as it should because sometimes adds a new homepage):

```
cd ~/.config/google-chrome/Default && cat ./Preferences | jq '.session.startup_urls[]="http://myhomepage"' > Pref && mv ./Pref ./Preferences
```

You'll have to install:

```
sudo apt-get install jq gnome-schedule
```

Then open `gnome-schedule` and create recurrent tasks with that command for every homepage you want.

Comment: Wouldn't that work only when launching chrome, rather than each time you see your homepage?

Comment: @VicAche yes it only works if when you launch Chrome